# Running application on windows When someone logs in

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010, authentication

I have written a windows application in Visual Basic which i want to run automatically when someone enters the password to log in. For example, i have locked my computer, and when i enter the password to unlock it, i want an app to run. But I have no idea how to do it.

Can anyone suggest any method for it?
Thanks

Comment: Windows Service is what you need.

Comment: Here's a link I found http://www.howtogeek.com/138159/how-to-enable-programs-and-custom-scripts-to-run-at-boot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to go = [Task scheduler library....](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/606876/How-to-create-a-task-in-Windows-Task-Scheduler)

[Read this one too...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx)